# Azure: create storage account with container and upload blob to it in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to create a storage account in Azure and upload a blob into it using their python SDK.
I managed to create an account like this:

```
client = get_client_from_auth_file(StorageManagementClient)
storage_account = client.storage_accounts.create(
        resourceGroup,
        name,
        StorageAccountCreateParameters(
            sku=Sku(name=SkuName.standard_ragrs),
            enable_https_traffic_only=True,
            kind=Kind.storage,
            location=region)).result()
```

The problem is that later I'm trying to build a container and I don't know what to insert as "account_url"
I have tried doing:

```
client = get_client_from_auth_file(BlobServiceClient, account_url=storage_account.primary_endpoints.blob)
return client.create_container(name)
```

But I'm getting:

`azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: The specified resource does not exist`

I did manage to create a container using:

```
client = get_client_from_auth_file(StorageManagementClient)
return client.blob_containers.create(
    resourceGroup,
    storage_account.name,
    name,
    BlobContainer(),
    public_access=PublicAccess.Container
)
```

But later when I'm trying to upload a blob using BlobServiceClient or BlobClien I still need the "account_url" so I'm still getting an error:

`azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: The specified resource does not exist`

Anyone can help me to understand how do I get the account_url for a storage account I created with the SDK?

**EDIT:**
I managed to find a workaround to the problem by creating the connection string from the storage keys.

```
storage_client = get_client_from_auth_file(StorageManagementClient)
storage_keys = storage_client.storage_accounts.list_keys(resource_group, account_name)
    storage_key = next(v.value for v in storage_keys.keys)
    return BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(
        'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;' +
        f'AccountName={account_name};' +
        f'AccountKey={storage_key};' +
        'EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net')
```

This works but I thin George Chen answer is more elegant.

Comment: Can you print `client` you got from this line `client = get_client_from_auth_file(BlobServiceClient, account_url=storage_account.primary_endpoints.blob)`?

Comment: Yes, I get ```<azure.storage.blob._blob_service_client.BlobServiceClient object at 0x103218be0>``` btw if I print ```client.account_name```  it is the right name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce this problem, then I found `get_client_from_auth_file` could not pass the credential to the `BlobServiceClient`, cause if just create `BlobServiceClient` with `account_url` without credential it also could print the account name.

So if you want to use a credential to get BlobServiceClient, you could use the below code, then do other operations.

```
credentials = ClientSecretCredential(
    'tenant_id',
    'application_id',
    'application_secret'
)

blobserviceclient=BlobServiceClient(account_url=storage_account.primary_endpoints.blob,credential=credentials)
```

If you don't want this way, you could create the `BlobServiceClient` with the account key.

```
client = get_client_from_auth_file(StorageManagementClient,auth_path='auth')

storage_account = client.storage_accounts.create(
        'group name',
        'account name',
        StorageAccountCreateParameters(
            sku=Sku(name=SkuName.standard_ragrs),
            enable_https_traffic_only=True,
            kind=Kind.storage,
            location='eastus',)).result()
storage_keys = client.storage_accounts.list_keys(resource_group_name='group name',account_name='account name')
storage_keys = {v.key_name: v.value for v in storage_keys.keys}
blobserviceclient=BlobServiceClient(account_url=storage_account.primary_endpoints.blob,credential=storage_keys['key1'])
blobserviceclient.create_container(name='container name')
```

Comment: I managed to find another workaround to the problem by creating the connection string from the account name and the storage keys but your solution looks more elegant.
I'm Adding my solution in the post for comparison.
Thanks!